# "although" and "yet"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, clauses

> Although he's got a good job now, he yet complains.

Does the sentence sound natural? When "yet" is used as an adverb, can "although" and "yet" appear in the same sentence?

Comment: *[Although/Even though] he's got several bad days in a row, he hasn't complained yet. Not yet. Not just yet.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. I suspect OP wants to use yet as a conjunction and not as an adverb in their sentence.

Comment: @Laure But the OP wrote *When "yet" is used as a adverb, ...*

Comment: @DamkerngT. sorry, I missed it! - seemed so illogical. But you're right I've added something to my answer.

Comment: Perhaps: _"Although he's got a good job now, he yet **still** complains."_

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound natural at all. Even if you wrote:

> *Although he's got a good job now, yet he complains.

which would be a more natural place for *yet*.

The use of *though* and *yet* seem to be redundant here, and I would only use one **or** the other:

> He's got a good job now, yet he complains.
>   Although he's got a good job now, he complains.
>   He complains although he's got a good job now.

But here I was using *yet* as a conjunction.
If you want to use it as an adverb - which introduces a reference to time  - then Damkerng's answer is the right one.

> Although he's got a good job now, he hasn't complained yet.

This last sentence is grammatically correct but its meaning is illogical, it is difficult to imagine someone who has a good job complaining.

Comment: Also "[Although/Even though] he's got a good job now, he still complains." and "He still complains [even though/although] he's got a good job now."

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ which has a slightly different meaning because "still" here would mean "he continues to complain" and not "nevertheless" (which could be another possibility) as with "yet" or "although",  .

Answer (score 0):

No, that does not natural. I had already typed "but the words can sound natural in the same sentence", and then I [racked my brains](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38630/which-is-correct-rack-my-brain-or-wrack-my-brain) to come up with an example. After five minutes of trying, I couldn't come up with a natural sounding sentence containing both words. Hmm

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you should say, "Although he has done a good job, he *still* complains.

"Yet" and "still are sometimes treated as synonyms. In this case, they are *not.*

That is, "still" works here and "yet" does not.